# Django: how to get the latest related object

Tags: django

I'm working on optimization Django queries and struggling with getting the last related item.

Models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CarTechnicalInspection(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    date_to = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_to', ]
```

View:

```
cars = Car.objects.all()
for car in cars:
    ti = car.cartechnicalinspection_set.last() #hit DB query for each car iteration!
    if ti and ti.date_to < timezone.now():
         #do something
```

How to Annotate the last Technical Inspection for each car without a DB query for each car? Thanks!

P.S. prefetch_related('cartechnicalinspection_set') does not work

Comment: Try this 
`cars = Car.objects.filter(cartechnicalinspection__date_to__lt=timezone.now())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need all the cars that the `date_to` is before `timezone.now()` which is now and you need the the `date_to` for these cars.

```
from django.db.models import Max

# Filter: cars with date_to less than timezone.now()
# Annotate: attach the greatest date_to as date_to to each car object.

cars = Car.objects.filter(cartechnicalinspection__date_to__lt=timezone.now()).annotate(date_to=Max('cartechnicalinspection__date_to'))
```

Now if you print them like this:

```
for car in cars:
    print(car.date_to)
```

You'll get the `date_to` for each car that the `date_to` less than `timezone.now()`